# How does Disney market Captain America outside of America?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america

The Marvel movies have been successfully marketed in America and outside of it. A staple of these movies has been Captain America, who is clearly a United States centric character. How has Disney (the company behind these movies) marketed a US centric superhero to a non-US audience?

Comment: Apologies in advance if I'm in the wrong StackExchange. It was this or a business one and I felt the question would be of more interest here!

Comment: Perhaps not surprisingly, "Captain America: The First Avenger" performed better overseas than in the US by a smaller ratio than the first Avengers film did. That said, it still made more money out of the US than in it.

Comment: America is quite a well-known country... and even if they *are* in America, the film could be anywhere. Plus everyone is used to Hollywood, with American scenery and American actors with American accents.

Comment: Ain't no American accents in the German release of the films.  All synchronized with German voice actors.

Comment: Can you recall any example where Hollywood *tuned down* the Americaness of its products for international release. They just go full MERICA and the rest of the world has to suck it up.

Comment: In Brazil and Chile and Peru and some other territories I believe they call him Captain North America. In Hawaii and Alaska they call him Captain Lower-Fourty-Eight and they have to pay extra for shipping.

Comment: One should remember that while Mr. America is certainly very American, most Hollywood movies are very American. People have gotten used to this after almost a century of Hollywood movies. The average Hollywood movie is laughably "patriotic". Additionally, the main reason why those terrible Superhero movies are produced is because they are popular in Asia - and like any other financially successful superhero movie, Captain America earned most money outside the US. I do not think the main audience for these movies cares what the movie is about as long as there are explosions

Comment: It's Captain America not Captain USA so it's not a country but a continent in his name.

Answer (score 5):

"From the creators of Iron Man", that's how.
Iron Man was super popular. So are superhero films. Even if the comics themselves are pretty niche here (like Captain America), people flock to the cinema because it's superheroes.

Answer (score 5):

In Germany at least, they try not to mention the name of Captain America in the title at all. Case in Point:

> Captain America: The First Avenger
>
> The Return of the First Avenger (a.k.a. Captain America: The Winter Soldier)
>
> The First Avenger: Civil War (a.k.a. Captain America: Civil War)

Maybe, because they think "If we never mention the characters name, maybe our audience will forget about his name".

But then again, german movie titles ALWAYS get turned to whatever the hell Execs want them to be.

Comment: Speaking for Belgium, we've simply used Captain America, there was no alteration. I don't quite understand the need to avoid using the name, the origin story of the character is that he was used to rally American troops.

Comment: Exactly, I mean you can keep giving him different names on the billboard, but they call him captain america in the movie all the time. No one calls him First avenger

Answer (score 0):

Disney has marketed Captain America as an Avenger after release of 2012 *The Avengers* movie. And also as "From studios that bought you Marvel's Avengers!".

While before that it war marketed as "From the Studios that bought you IRONMAN!".

Till the release of Civil War Captain America it self became a brand so it was not marketed as above two strategies rather than it was "Divided we fall!", "Captain America 3", while the posters of Civil War almost resembled an Avengers type gathering so people were attracted to it. Specially some posters feature Ironman vs Captain America which was also a USB.

Comment: Can you add any images of these posters?